Plugin Duplication Wraning while mapping over Array to render Multiple TipTap Editors (React js)
I'm trying to make a productivity application that requires an editor so I'm using TipTap. On main screen there are 4 divs and when you click on one div it opens a different instance of the editor.
<Fragment key={card.id}>
                <div
                    className="priorityCard"
                    id={card.name}
                    onClick={() => handleCardClick(card.id)}
                >
                    Hello1
                </div>

                {card.isActive && (
                    <>
                        <TipTap />

                        <button
                            className={`${styles.closeBtn}`}
                            
                        >
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </>
                )}
            </Fragment>

It's working fine but the problem is I'm getting a warning

"Duplicate extension names found: ['orderedList', 'listItem']. This
can lead to issues.

" when I open an editor twice or if I close one editor and open another. I guess it's related to rendering multiple editors  on a single page. Is there a solution for that or is it okay to keep the code like this.
